# :4200/null Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am using Angular 5.0.0 and AngularFire2 5

The error in the console appears when I am on a page that loads the information from firebase using the UID passed through the url. The information is then displayed in a form. This is part of my CRUD more specifically the Update/Edit section.

The error I receive in the console when the page is loaded:

```
:4200/null Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Everything seems to be working properly? I'm not sure how to diagnose this error. I would consider myself to be a beginner so please direct me in the way of learning and understanding. If there is anything else I need to supply please let me know below.

Thanks for your time.

product-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../../category.service';
import { ProductService } from '../../product.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$;
  product = {};

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();

    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id) {
      this.productService.get(id).take(1).subscribe(p => this.product = p);
    }
  }

  save(product) {
    this.productService.create(product);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

product-form.component.html

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6">
      <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(form.value)">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Title</label>
              <input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.title" name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" required>
              <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
                Title is required.
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input #price="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="product.price" name="price" id="price" type="number" class="form-control" required [min]="0">
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="price.touched && price.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="price.errors.required">Price is required.</div>
                  <div *ngIf="price.errors.min">Price should be 0 or higher.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select #category="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="product.category" name="category" id="category" class="form-control" required>
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option *ngFor="let category of categories$ | async" [value]="category.key">{{ category.payload.val().name }}</option>
                </select>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="category.touched && category.invalid">
                  Category is required.
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imageUrl">Image URL</label>
                <input #imageUrl="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="product.imageUrl" name="imageUrl" id="imageUrl" type="text" class="form-control" required url>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="imageUrl.touched && imageUrl.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.required">Image URL is required.</div>
                  <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.url">Please enter a valid URL.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

          </form>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" [src]="product.imageUrl">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{ product.title }}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{ product.price | currency: 'USD': symbol }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: apparently you are doing a query on some url with a variable, and this variable at the moment of the problematic call has a null value. Since you do not show where you are doing your calls, it is hard to help more.

Comment: more code please

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is when the page first loads the product image url is not loaded from database at first. So...

at the bottom of the html template add a *ngIf directive to the product.imageUrl

```
*ngIf="product.imageUrl"
```

product-form.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" [src]="product.imageUrl" *ngIf="product.imageUrl">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{ product.title }}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{ product.price | currency: 'USD': symbol }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```